# angular 10 subscribe of http.get is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I created backend in Node.js and frontend in angular2+. I want to do a simple todo-list. I made a GET, POST, and DELETE methods, and these works correctly. The problem is when I subscribe my `getTodos` function, I not getting any updates when todosList is changed by POST or DELETE in the meanwhile.

Here is the code for todo.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Todo } from '../models/todo.model';

    @Injectable()
    export class TodoService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
        const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/'
        const todoUrl = 'api/todo'
        return this.http.get<Todo[]>(baseUrl + todoUrl)
      } 
    }
```

Have typescript code app.component.ts

```js
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
      providers: [ TodoService ]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'todo';
      taskHeader = ['User', 'Todo', 'Is done', 'Has attachment']
      todos: Todo[];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private todoService: TodoService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.todoService.getTodos()
          .subscribe((res) =>  {this.todos = res
          console.log('this.todos', this.todos)}
        )
      }

      send(data) {
        const addUserUrl = 'api/todo'
        
        let addUserHeaders = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const todo: Todo = {
          userName: 'test',
          todo: data,
          isDone: true,
          hasAttachment: false
        }
        
        this.http.post(baseUrl + addUserUrl, todo,  {headers: addUserHeaders, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((x) => console.log(x) )
      }  
      
      deleteTask(todoId) {
        const addUserUrl = 'api/todo'
        this.http.delete(`${baseUrl}${addUserUrl}/${todoId} `, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((s) => {
          console.log(s);
        })
      }
    }
```

Here is api.controller.js

```js
    module.exports = (app) => {
      app.use(bodyParser.json())
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

      app.get('/api/todo', (req, res) => {
        Todos.find({}).then(function (todos) {
          res.send(todos);
        });
      })

      app.post('/api/todo', (req, res) => {
        if (req.body.id) {
          Todos.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
            todo: req.body.todo, isDone:
            req.body.isDone, hasAttachment:
            req.body.hasAttachment
          }, 
          (err, todo) => {
            if (err) throw err
            res.send('Post Success')
          })
        }

        else {
          const newTodo = Todos({
            userName: req.body.userName,
            todo: req.body.todo,
            isDone: req.body.isDone,
            hasAttachment: req.body.hasAttachment
          })
          newTodo.save((err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            res.send('Post Success')
          })
        }    
      });

      app.delete('/api/todo/:id', (req,res) => {
        Todos.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err
          res.send('Delete Success')
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: First things first: if you call the Todo endpoint inside the browser, does it answer with the expected JSON?

Comment: What do you mean by "meanwhile"? Http is request-response based, so your get call is only fetching your data once. You could return updated data by post and delete or modify the todo list in java script when the calls return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Subscribe` doesn't work the way you think. If you subscribe to `getTodos` the request gets sent once, you get the response and that's it. There is no connection anymore that would get notified about any change in your database when there is a post/delete request.

You have several options:

- whenever you make a post/delete request instead of sending `Post Success` or `Delete Success` as a response you send the database content.
- after a successful post/delete request you modify the data in your frontend
- you use websockets as a steady connection between your frontend and backend. this options comes close to how you think `subscribe` works

Personally I would implement the first or second option.